# Routeprovider Angular JS Update

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have this piece of code from a mobile website that used to work perfectly.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    // launch
}, false);

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        when('/home', {templateUrl: 'views/home.html'})
        .when('/about', {templateUrl: 'views/about.html'})
        .otherwhise({redirectTo: '/home'})
});
```

I updated to a newer version of angular, and I got a error.
I found out on other threads that ngRoute is now separate from angular.js so I've added it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Now my error is :

> Uncaught Error: [[$injector:modulerr]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr) Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [[$injector:unpr]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) Unknown provider: $routeProvider

I don't understand why $routeProvider is still unknow now that I've added the angular route script.

I tried couple fix that I've found here but can't make it work. Any ideas of what I missed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ngRoute is now separate from angular.js so to use it you have to inject it as a dependency, like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

as for the following error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Usually, this error appears when angular-route.js is not loaded for some reason.

The said project has mismatched versions for angular and its module, for example:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

so Make these versions match. They should likely be `.../1.6.4/angular.js` and `.../1.6.4/angular-route.js`

Comment: Thank for your answer. I tried, I had another error :
angular.js:138 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
ReferenceError: when is not defined.